# How can I find out a list of all configuration files loaded by Xorg?

Tags: linux, xorg, xorg.conf

There's a lot of lists of places where these files can be found, but can I see the actual list of what is loaded?

Comment: `strace startx 2>&1 | grep open`

Answer (score 0):

Xorg keeps it's logs as /var/log/Xorg.x.log

Since the logs record which configuration files are being used, all you have to do is

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep Using.config
```

Which will tell you the paths to the config files and the config directory.